# What keys do the bits in the XQueryPointer's mask_return values represent?

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

In X11 programming we sometimes use the XQueryPointer function to determine the location of the mouse on the screen.

In xlib.h we can also see that this function populates an integer called mask_return with individual flags representing key-presses:

```
extern Bool XQueryPointer(
    Display*,
    Window,
    Window*,
    Window*,
    int*,
    int*,
    int*,
    int*,
    unsigned int*  /* mask_return */
);
```

I've used the following code to experiment with this:

```
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
int screen = DefaultScreen(display);
Window rootWin = RootWindow(display, screen);
Window qRoot;
Window qChild;
int qRootX;
int qRootY;
int qChildX;
int qChildY;
unsigned int qMask;
while(true)
{
  if(XQueryPointer(display, rootWin, &qRoot, &qChild, &qRootX, &qRootY, &qChildX, &qChildY, &qMask))
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 8; i++)
    {
      int mask = 1 << sizeof(int) * 8 - i - 1;
      if(mask & qMask)
      {
        printf("1");
      }
      else
      {
        printf("0");
      }
    }
    printf("(%d)\n", qMask);
  }
}
```

Using this method I've been able to isolate the following flags:

- 00000000000000000000000000000001(1): This flag is on if either the left or right shift key is pressed when XQueryPointer is called.
- 00000000000000000000000000001000(4): This flag is on if either the left or right control key is pressed when XQueryPointer is called.
- 00000000000000000000000000010000(8): This flag is on if either the left or right alt key is pressed when XQueryPointer is called.
- 00000000000000000000001000000000(256):  This flag is on if mouse1 is pressed when XQueryPointer is called.
- 00000000000000000000010000000000(512):  This flag is on if mouse3 is pressed when XQueryPointer is called.
- 00000000000000000000100000000000(1024):  This flag is on if mouse2 is pressed when XQueryPointer is called.

You would think for a 30+ year old API that documentation of these flags would be widely available, but I can't seem to find mention of them anywhere.

**Does anybody know if/what the remaining flags are used for or where I can read more about them?**

**Furthermore, can I trust that the same flags will always mean the same things on different systems?**

Comment: This may help a bit: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "same flags mean the same things on different systems"? ShiftMask will always correspond to the shift modifier, but what keys trigger modifiers is a property of the keyboard layout and can actually differ.

Comment: @UliSchlachter I was looking out for situations where different distros might raise flags for the same event at different locations within the mask.  For instance, maybe CentOS flips the 16th bit for a mouse1 event instead of the 8th bit.  Since, as your answer indicates, the mask is defined within X itself, that seems very unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from `X.h`:

```
/* Key masks. Used as modifiers to GrabButton and GrabKey, results of QueryPointer,
   state in various key-, mouse-, and button-related events. */

#define ShiftMask       (1<<0)
#define LockMask        (1<<1)
#define ControlMask     (1<<2)
#define Mod1Mask        (1<<3)
#define Mod2Mask        (1<<4)
#define Mod3Mask        (1<<5)
#define Mod4Mask        (1<<6)
#define Mod5Mask        (1<<7)
```

and a little later in the same file:

```
/* button masks.  Used in same manner as Key masks above. Not to be confused
   with button names below. */

#define Button1Mask     (1<<8)
#define Button2Mask     (1<<9)
#define Button3Mask     (1<<10)
#define Button4Mask     (1<<11)
#define Button5Mask     (1<<12)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I followed the XQueryPointer definition to xlib.h where the only description was "mask return."